# How to remove the Largest Contentful Paint element from Lighthouse Report?

Tags: angular, lighthouse

Below is my code in the angular .html file:

`<h3 class="u-h3 mb-4">Personal Details</h3>`

I get the error in Diagnostics of Lighthouse under "Largest Contentful Paint element" section  : This is the largest contentful element painted within the viewport.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: There is no CSS associated with this element? And it is the only element in your whole angular app? Nothing else is shown on the screen?

Comment: I am using bootstrap CSS `u-h3 mb-4`. Page contains many more element. But when I remove this element the error shifts to the next big text on page. But if I remove the CSS from this element and make it simple like this `<p>Personal Details</p>` the error 
 "Largest Contentful Paint element" goes away.

Comment: if it is not the only element then add an exapmle of what actually is on the page. And what you expect to happen. Without any code we can't really help you.